# Debug statement truncated in Raw Log

Tags: apex, debugging, debug-logs

It seems like something was implemented last spring that truncates long debug statements in the developer console. All the solutions say to view the raw log. I opened the raw log from both the developer console and also from the debug logs page but both are also truncated. If anyone knows how to fix this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain types of debug statements are "always" truncated (assuming they reach some arbitrary length), notably Map, List, and Set values that are debugged directly to the log.

For example:

```
System.debug([SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 50000]);
```

Also, if you reach the maximum log size (20MB), then there will definitely be truncation. If you need to see the entire value, consider using a [Check Point](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&type=5) instead. Also, see this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/developer_console/developer_console_checkpoints) on how to use Check Points.

Serializing the object (`JSON.serialize(someValue)`) can also allow much larger values to be printed out, although not all objects can be serialized this way.